# My audio files saved in firebase storage do not sound

Tags: firebase, android-mediaplayer, firebase-storage

has anyone ever had trouble playing a recorded audio file? I made a firebase voice mail app. I record the audio well but during playback, I hear nothing, I checked the volume of the device and I even set the max vomume in a programmable way. the sound is still not audible, I hear nothing at all. Do you have any ideas for me?

[image]

Here is the voice  registration code :

```
private void startRecording() {
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
            Log.d("volume MANAGER" , " volumeManager " + am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            outputfile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/new audio.mp3";
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(96000);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputfile);
            try {
                mediaRecorder.prepare();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mediaRecorder.start();
                mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
                Log.d("volume actuel" , " volume" + mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d(" pb start", "start");
            }
            Log.d("volume actuel" , " volume" + mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude());

    }
```

Stoped Recording Code :

private void stopRecording() {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

```
    try {

        mediaRecorder.stop();
        Log.d("Stop recording ", "stop recording");
    } catch (IllegalStateException ie) {
        ie.getMessage();
    }
    mediaRecorder.release();
    mediaRecorder = null;
}
```

Code to start playing record :
 private void play_songs() {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(FriendList.this, Uri.parse(outputfile));
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(150,150);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Start playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "audio doesn't play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Prepare failed.: status", " ALORS"+ equals(e.getMessage()));
        Log.d("Catch De play song", "message " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Here is the code to execute methode when user press recording Button :

```
    btnrecoder.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {


                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(FriendList.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                            FriendList.RECORD_AUDIO);

                } else {
                    startRecording();
                    btnrecoder.setText(" Recording start...");

                }


            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                stopRecording();
                UploadFile();
                btnrecoder.setText(" Recording stopped...");

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I used   Log.d("volume actuel" , " volume" + mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()); on Started recording methode to verify volume when recording and i get this : the volume is 0
[image]

Comment: What are you asking here? We're not going to have any idea what's wrong with your code without seeing it. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry, it's because i posted so many unanswered ones that i posted without a code. I'm editing my post right away. Thanks